# How to find gas station using Google Places API?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I'm looking to find gas stations around based on the location I provided. And it seems that the query string that I provide to the Google API is not really correct, leading to the desired result.

Here is the URL

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json

And this is my query string:

> ?**location**=40.316828,%20-82.839840&**radius**=50000&**type**=gas_station&**keyword**=cruise&**key**=My_Google_Key

Response returned current>:

> {
> "html_attributions" : [],
> "results" : [],
> "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
> }

Comment: I get results from that query, but the location is in Columbus, OH ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/zxbsjt6y/)) Nowhere near Vietnam.  Actually, looking at your picture, the coordinates are completely different.

Comment: Wait a minute, that cordinate from Ohio, not Columbus. Im try to test if happen only VietNam or not. Can you try this VietNam cordinate: 10.778804, 106.698475

Comment: I get results for those coordinates when I remove the "keyword=cruise" parameter. Is that a vital part of your search? https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=10.778804,106.698475&radius=5000&type=gas_station&key=YOUR_KEY

Comment: Thanks, you save my life

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple, just remove the "**keyword**" parameter then everything will be ok. If this param is declared, the API will only return results with the same value as the param

Here is my original URL:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=40.316828,%20-82.839840&radius=50000&type=gas_station&keyword=cruise&key=My_Google_Key

Replace with this URL:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=40.316828,%20-82.839840&radius=50000&type=gas_station&key=My_Google_Key